# Loading credentials from config

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am writing simple rest client with spring boot. In my service class i am using RestTemplate. How to avoid hardcoding url and ApiKey? I tried to use application.properties file and Value annotation but i get null pointer exception.
Edit: 
Injected fields via constructor (using Value annotation). Is it a good practice?

Comment: How are you loading that property file into your Template? You need to define a @PropertySource in your configuration class

Comment: From what i read i dont need to define it if i am using default application.properties location. Am i correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should I store development credentials on a Spring Boot project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899911/where-should-i-store-development-credentials-on-a-spring-boot-project)

Answer (score 0):

It is wise of you to not want to store url and ap ikey in your application.

I recommend having a properties file stored in your home directory and then reference that file at startup time.

`java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/another-location.properties`*

*Taken from [Properties with Spring and Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring).