# Having configuration files outside jar file in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, apache-camel

I have a Spring boot camel application whose directory structure is like this

[image]

I want to convert this project into a jar file. But I want 3 files outside my jar so that I don't need to redeploy my application again and again when the configuration is changed.
those 3 files are

1. application.properties
2. CamelContext.xml
3. sql.properties

   I have the flexibility to hardcode the path of the file location. Can anyone help me out how do I achieve this?

Comment: 1. Supported out-of-the-box, 2 and 3 give file paths or the ability to configure the paths to load from.

Comment: can you please elaborate for 2) and 3)

Comment: Try checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754459/spring-boot-how-to-read-properties-file-outside-jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have resolved the issue I will post the solution for anyone who is trying to achieve the same thing.

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    /*To load CamelContext.xml file */
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    CustomResourceLoader customResourceLoader = (CustomResourceLoader) context.getBean("customResourceLoader");

    customResourceLoader.showResourceData();

/*To load the properties file*/ 

    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .properties("spring.config.name:application.properties,sql",
                    "spring.config.location=D:/external/application.properties,D:/external/sql.properties")
            .build().run(args);

    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();


}
```

Create a class CustomResourceLoader.java in same package as that of main class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;


public class CustomResourceLoader implements ResourceLoaderAware {

    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
    }

    public void showResourceData() throws IOException
    {
        //This line will be changed for all versions of other examples
        Resource banner = resourceLoader.getResource("file:D:/external/CamelContext.xml");
        InputStream in = banner.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    }




}
```

also, create an applicationContext.xml file in src/main/resources

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
<bean id="customResourceLoader" class="main.CustomResourceLoader"></bean>

</beans>
```

Appendix -

- http://www.java2novice.com/spring-boot/load-external-configuration-files/
- https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/how-to-load-external-resources-files-into-spring-context/