# read from spring xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={file1.class, file2.class})
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class Trans{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Trans.class, args);
    }

}
```

When the XML exist in the jar its working properly and the XML is read. I wish to remove the XML from the jar to an existing folder on the machine.
When doing it, the XML is not read. How can I read the XML from the machine file system and not from the jar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637665/having-configuration-files-outside-jar-file-in-spring-boot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ImportResource(locations = {"file:/some/resource/path/applicationContext.xml"})
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. Where are your `applicationContext.xml` located?