# Can Activiti engine(activiti bpmn 2.0) read a file located outside the classpath?

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I have a spring boot activiti project and my activiti bpmn file is located in classpath: `src/main/resources/processes`. What I need is, instead of reading from classpath I need to read the file from the system file path or outside from the resources folder.

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754459/spring-boot-how-to-read-properties-file-outside-jar this might help

Answer (score 0):

Just add below configuration in your application.properties file.

```
spring.activiti.checkProcessDefinitions = true
spring.activiti.processDefinitionLocationPrefix = file:D:/Users/ActivitiProcess/
spring.activiti.processDefinitionLocationSuffixes = *.bpmn20.xml, *.bpmn
```