# Load application.properties outside jar

Tags: spring-boot, jar, properties, path

How can I set application.properties in SpringBoot outside .jar? I would link to this file and load properties from code.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754459/spring-boot-how-to-read-properties-file-outside-jar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot how to read properties file outside jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754459/spring-boot-how-to-read-properties-file-outside-jar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By convention, Spring Boot looks for an externalized configuration file – application.properties or application.yml – in 4 predetermined locations in the following order of precedence:

1. /config subdirectory of the current directory
2. The current directory
3. classpath /config package
4. The classpath root

You can place your application.properties in any of the 4 locations without needing to give the location of application.properties while executing the jar. If you want to given any other custom location , then you will have to provide the path of the config location while executing the jar:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=<path-to-file> myProject.jar
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar