# Using different application.properties in java -jar without Spring

Tags: java, jar, application.properties

I have to deploy a simple `.jar` file in a production environment. For security reasons, I'm not able to write production credentials inside the `application.properties`.

I retrieve properties like so:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream is = PropertiesLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
properties.load(is);
```

Since the `.jar` contains `/application.properties` at its root directory, it will be read correctly. I need to outsource this `application.properties` and I was wondering if there was a way simply by adding a parameter for the `java -jar App.jar` command.

I only found parameters for a Spring project ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62952711/11961036)), which are not for me because this `.jar` is plain JDBC Java.

I would like to avoid using a `FileInputStream` and giving the file path as parameter, like so:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
String applicationPropertiesPath = args[0];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(applicationPropertiesPath);
properties.load(fis);
```

And then launching the `.jar` with `java -jar App.jar /path/to/application.properties`.. But I will, if there are no other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I adopted is copying the external `application.properties` inside the `.jar` file, using this command:

```
jar uf App.jar /path/to/application.properties
```

Works flawlessly.